# Is this proof of the First Transfinite Induction Principle incomplete or incorrect?

Tags: set-theory, transfinite-induction

Context: Cheating on my homework.

I am studying Smullyan and Fitting's *Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis* (2010: rev.ed.) and I have reached Chapter 4: Superinduction, Well-Ordering and Choice: $\S 1$ Introduction to Well-Ordering, Theorem $1.8$ (Transfinite Induction Principle $1$).

> Let $A$ be a well-ordered class under $\le$. Let $P$ be a property satisfying the following condition: For every $x \in A$, if $P$ holds for every $y < x$, $P$ holds for $x$. Then $P$ holds for every element of $A$.

The proof of this theorem is offered up as follows:

> If $P$ failed to hold for some element of $A$, then there must be a least element $x$ of $A$ for which $P$ fails to hold. Then for every $y < x$, $P$ holds for $y$. This violates the hypothesis. $\blacksquare$

And yet, suppose the "some element" that $P$ fails to hold for is the smallest element of $A$.

Then the set of elements that $P$ fails to hold for, of which $x$ is the smallest, has no $y$ for which $y < x$.

Hence $P$ holds for no elements of $A$.

While this does not appear to invalidate the statement of the theorem, it *does* appear to invalidate the proof.

Is the proof as given above in S&F actually incorrect and/or incomplete, or am I failing once more to misunderstand the concept of vacuous truth?

- If the former, what would need to be done to salvage the proof?
- If the latter, where is my thinking incorrect?

Comment: "And yet, suppose the "some element" that P fails to hold for is the smallest element of A." That can't happen: P is true for everything less than the smallest element, so by hypothesis it is true for the smallest element.

Comment: @MatthewTowers So that needs to be added to the proof to complete the proof?

Comment: I don’t understand why you think this invalidates the proof. Which specific step of the proof does your argument invalidate?

Comment: @MarkSaving becos stoopid dum herbs like me need it speld out so dey unerstand.

Comment: Mind you there is a important typo in your induction hypothesis, with  a $y$ in place of $x$.  Please correct it!

Comment: @Ruy Apologies, are you unable to edit?

Comment: No, I could but perhaps you should!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the misunderstanding is precisely related to "vacuous truths",  as you said.

When you state your hypothesis:

> For every $x \in A$, if $P$ holds for every $y < x$, then $P$ holds for $x$.

and you plug in the smallest element of $A$ for $x$,   the hypothesis reads:

> if $P$ holds for every $y $ in the empty set,  then $P$ holds for $x$.

Notice that any property,  whatsoever,  holds for every $y $ in the empty set!

Moreover,  when an implication has a
manifestly true antecedent,  like the one above, the truth value of the whole thing is the truth value of the consequent.

In other words, the above instance of the hypothesis simply says that $P$ holds for $x$, period.   Hence it is already a
contradiction to assume that $P$ fails for the smallest element.

PS: In the usual induction process, as taught at more elementary levels, it is usually explicitly assumed  that the
given property holds for the smallest element,  namely the natural number zero.  We could therefore include a similar
hypothesis that $P$ holds for the least element, but this is actually superfluous by the reasoning above.

Comment: Re the PS: the 2nd principle of transfinite induction, as presented by S&F, does make explicit reference to the smallest element, successor elements, and the limit elements in the conventional tripartite presentation of the PTI (I have just read a bit further down the page in my copy of the book itself). I understand that we are not at elementary level here, despite the obvious fact that my own personal mathematical skills are such that even the elementary level is way over my head, but I will keep trying and maybe I'll get it.